# Negative voltage value for AD620 amplifier

Tags: amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, negative-voltage

I am using AD620 to amplify the signal of a pressure sensor, and a negative supply voltage must be added to V- pin. should the negative voltage value be the same as the positive supply voltage? or any value within the range will be suitable?
[image: Source image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stay within minimum and maximum ranges on the datasheet, but it's not that simple. You have to make sure nothing saturates internally and the output is capable of the required swing.

Analog Devices now provides a convenient [online tool](https://tools.analog.com/en/diamond/?doc=AN-1401pdf#difL=-0.1&difR=0.1&difSl=-0.1&gain=100&l=-3&pr=AD620&r=3&sl=-3&tab=1&ty=1&vn=-15&vp=15&vr=0) called a diamond plot tool (from the shape of the limits) that allows you to check the supply voltages vs. input and output range and gain.

Here is an example with asymmetrical supply voltages and arbitrarily chosen gain and common mode voltage range:

[image]